# Renaming PDFs with script (Bookmarking)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make a script that you run it and you can Bookmark PDFs and then run a split script that will separate the pages. However this script that bookmarks them is mean't to rename them however it currently isn't and I can't see why.

This is my code and I need desperate help:

```
with open('+Renamed.csv', 'ab') as fout:
     writer = csv.writer(fout)
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
    filename_no_ext, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if ext.lower() == '.pdf':
        n = str(idx).zfill(8)
        new_filename = name_fmt % (ftoday, n)
        new_filepath = os.path.join(path, new_filename)
        new_filename_no_ext, ext = os.path.splitext(new_filename)

        while new_filename_no_ext in db_list:
            idx += 1
            n = str(idx).zfill(8)
            new_filename = name_fmt % (ftoday, n)
            new_filepath = os.path.join(path, new_filename)
            new_filename_no_ext, ext = os.path.splitext(new_filename)

        while os.path.exists(new_filepath):
            cmd = 'INSERT into [BLACKSTONE].[dbo].[Filename] ' \
                  'VALUES (?)'
            cursor.execute(cmd, new_filename_no_ext)

            cnxn.commit()

            idx += 1
            n = str(idx).zfill(8)
            new_filename = name_fmt % (ftoday, n)
            new_filepath = os.path.join(path, new_filename)
            new_filename_no_ext, ext = os.path.splitext(new_filename)


        idx += 1

        print filepath
        try:
            os.rename(filepath, new_filepath)
            print new_filepath
        except:
            print >>sys.stderr, 'Unable to rename:', filepath
            sys.exit()
```

Please help, I have tried to complete this for roughly a weekend now and I can't see why nothing is renaming, it's only mean't to rename the files in the +Renamed folder, please let me know if you'd like to see the whole code.

Thanks!